# Can't set log_bin_trust_function_creators=1 on machine startup - MySQL 8.0

Tags: ubuntu, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to put the `log_bin_trust_function_creators=1` parameter into the `my.cnf` configuration file to set the variable correctly on startup on a machine with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. But every time I save the file with this line written in the config file,  when I try to access the db I can't log in and iIhave this error output message:

> ```
> mysql: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 23.
> mysql: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
> ```

When I use `SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;` the parameter and the db work fine, but I would prefer to not having to reboot the machine when I set this parameter.

The version that we're using is `mysql  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`

Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 8):

Put it under `mysqld`, there it should be found and set

```
[mysqld]
log-bin-trust-function-creators = 1
```

Comment: This is the most common mistake people make when options are not under the correct group header. +1 !!!

Comment: Hi, i've tried to do what you advice me but i can't find anything that contains mysqld

Comment: search for [mysqld] in a text editor and if it finds **nothing** add the **two** lines but you should have port bind-adress and much more in that section

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses a split config file.  The `[mysqld]` section you need to add this to is found in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf/mysqld.cnf`.